# re arrange php associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array:

```
$example = array();

$example ['one']   = array('first' => 'blue',
                           'second' => 'red');

$example ['two']   = array('third' => 'purple',
                           'fourth' => 'green');

$example ['three'] = array('fifth' => 'orange',
                           'sixth' => 'white');
```

Based on some input to the function, I need to change the order of the example array before the foreach loop processes my output:

```
switch($type)

case 'a':
//arrange the example array as one, two three
break;

case 'b':
//arrange the example array as two, one, three
break;

case 'c':
//arrange the example array in some other arbitrary manner
break;

foreach($example as $value){
        echo $value;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this without re-engineering all my code? I have a pretty indepth foreach loop that does the processing and if there was an easy way to simple re-order the array each time that would be really helpful.

Comment: What is the purpose of your "arbitrary array sorting?"  Are you simply trying to randomize the order?  Or, do you specifically want to shift the items around in a parametric fashion?

Comment: I guess the point is more that I need to sort them how I want and that doesn't fall into any readily available sorting criteria like alphabetical or numerical...I need it to be sorted precisely how I tell it to be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array-multisort) for your permutation. I assume that you know the permutation and don't need to derive it from the key names. Say, you want the order `two, three, one`, then **create a reference array** like that:

```
$permutation = array(3, 1, 2);
```

*Meaning:* first item goes to position 3, second item to position 1, third item to position 2

Then, after the `switch`, permute:

```
array_multisort($permutation, $example);
```

This will sort the `$permutation` array and apply the same order to `$example`.

Comment: since I am not using numeric keys will the permutation array work? This seems to be the route for me to take because you are absolutely right in that I do know the permutation I want for each situation.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the keys and array_multisort preserves non-numeric keys, so: yes, it will work

Comment: Yep this was the way to do it, thanks again. Took a bit to wrap my head around the permutations (haven't had to use them in awhile) but ultimately this was the simplest method given I knew the order of each case.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to find a silver bullet answer here.  You are going to probably need to write your own function for use with `uksort()`.

```
uksort($example, function ($a, $b) use $type {
    switch($type) {
        case 'a':
            if ($a === 'one' || $b === 'three') return 1;
            if ($a === 'three' || $b === 'one') return -1;
            if ($a === 'two' && $b === 'three') return 1;
            return -1;
            break;
        // and so on...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom sort function for each case and then use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). The first case could just use sort. The arbitrary sort needs to be logic you define.

Answer (score 0):

I see more ways to solve this, but not knowing more about I don't know what is better.

1. Make a pre-score (make a numeric value for each element, calculated in your "pretty in-depth foreach loop"), then sort the array by it using it as the main and single criteria.
2. If your criteria s are based on only numeric fields, ASC/DESC use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
3. make custom sorting functions for each case (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)